# How can I set an image for the Alienware Command Center of a game created with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know how to set up a banner like Apex or Fortnite in the image below for Unity games.
Applications made by Unity will automatically become icon images.

Application Config Dialog Banner in Player Settings sets the image of the dialog when the game is started, and I think it is not for displaying the banner outside.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit properties of game...